# getSript adds handler several times at the same object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have 2 divs, they have multiples elements and each element has options(events). In the first div, each element has a button that load, in the second div, the children elements. Those children have a edit button that opens a dialog where the user can edit.

Here is the script:

```
$("#Content").load("elements.php?id=5", function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({cache: true});
    $.getScript("../js/elements.js", function(){
        $.ajaxSetup({cache: false});
    });
})
```

The problem is: When I load `#Content` with its script, it`s works good only in the first time, it opens one dialog box, but if I load twice, it opens **two** dialog boxes, and three, etc.

How do I delete the last script I loaded?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are there any bindings? any live, etc? I am not sure if its your current code that is causing this issue or the elements.js being that I dont know what is inside of it. I do recommend checking out [Jquery stopImmediatePropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopImmediatePropagation/). I hope this can put you on the right path.

Comment: Thank you so much. I've been studing that, but i don't know how to use it, and i don´t know if it is what i need. elements.js has something like:
$("#BtAddElem").on("click", AddEl);
function AgregarIndic(){
    $(".NuevoIndic").dialog({
        height: 300,
        hide: "scale"
    });
 ....
}
Please, keep helping me, when i load the #Content several time, i getScript several times, and there's a moment that i press one time #BtAddElem, and it opens several dialog boxes. 

Dios los bendiga, espero me puedan seguir ayudando.

Comment: hey sorry, it was bed time for me :) but if you still need help just let me know.. Dios Tebendiga tambien.

Comment: Yes, i still need your help as soon as posible, Estoy en graves problemas. Thanks

Comment: cool np, if you can wait a bit, while I cook, or you can check my profile and email me your issue I will be more than happy to help. You can always create another post here.. anyways ya mismo vengo.

Comment: Excelent i appreciate that! thanks, i really want to solve this, how do i know your email?

Comment: Hi... can u still help me? i need it, please there are too many dialog boxes, and now we notice that when the user creates a new element, it creates several element, the same problem, i'm going to cry.

Comment: Do you have a link were I can see what you are doing? see if you can understand what I did here.. xlordt.linuxcode.com/~xlordt/mfwall/

Comment: I tried moving this to chat, but cant yet. So just fallow that link and we can solve it from there.

Comment: Thank you so much! one of the problems i had was that i did use bad the remove(), and xlordt changed my $.getScript, for  
 $.ajax 
     ({ 
       async: false,
       type: "GET",
       url:  "../js/Indicadores_Competencia.js",
       data: null,
       success: function (d) {
    //return false;
     }, dataType: 'script'
        });
Etc...
In other words, xlordt it the best!! thank you so much, what a beautiful and awesome acts you do here. God bless you so much!!
;) (very happy)